# Python Neural Network with (apparently) 3 input layers and a matrix output

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to make a NN (topic I don't know anything about, and reading didn't make it clear) that does the following:

takes an m x n matrix as first input, then a second and a third matrix and finally outs the resulting matrix. E.g:

```
[0,0,0,1,0,0]    [0,0,0,2,0,0]    [0,0,0,0,0,0]        [0,0,0,0,1,0]   
[0,0,0,1,0,0] => [0,0,1,0,1,0] => [0,0,0,1,0,0] yields [2,0,1,0,0,0] 
[1,0,1,0,1,0]    [1,0,0,0,0,0]    [0,1,0,0,1,0]        [0,1,0,1,0,0]
```

Note that I they are 1 matrix and not 3 vectors (I don't know how to do a giant squere bracket).

Other than having no clue how to do that (if it can be done), other concerns I have are:

- As seen in the first matrix the first and second row are the same, but the second matrix do not yields the same results. This can be due that the overall first matrix has an impact on that or not (I am working with data that is supposed to be "random", but that's exactly what I want to figure: how random it is).
- Most examples I've seen out just a single number, not a matrix. The numbers are between 0 and 1 (if I understand correctly because the sigmoid function is used), but I need them to be ints >= 0.

I hope I made it clearly enough.

Thank you very much!

P.S: I am sure this won't impact the general answer, but for the sake of completeness I will add that the matrix is 100 x 6.

Comment: One solution may be to input every value in the matrix as a separate node in the NN. Could explain why you need to put the input matrices consecutively? Why is that necessary?

Comment: Because I think the second matrix is dependant on the first matrix, the third dependant on just the second matrix or the first and second and the output matrix (the one I am trying to "guess") dependant on some or all the previous matrices.

Comment: Recurrent neural networks (like LSTMs) do this. Other than that you can use a feed forward network where you input multiple matrices in one go time. The shape (dimensions) of your input tensors can be anything you like. If you need the output to be of a particular type you can always do some transformations on it to conform to your needs. Could you provide a coding example of what you have tried?

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen Hi, thank you for your reply, I don't have any code because I don't know where even to start. Most code I've seen online I did not try because they are "simple" multiple binary input on 1 input layer and one output between 0 and 1.
I will check that LSTMs are and see if there is some code I can use.
What I am trying to do is really really long to explain, not sure if this site provides some form of private messages.

Comment: If reading didn't make it clear - _read more_. For example, [this great online book about ANNs](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com). And start from the bottom, from writing an ANN that just XORs two input numbers, from something simple.

Comment: No, no PM on SO (I wish we had). It seems you're pretty new to ANN's so I recommend against starting up with LSTMs, which are somewhat more complicated. You should probably get acquainted with the basics. I suggest going for some learning material based on Keras examples. Ultimately you have to have some training/input data and label/output data for the network to learn from. Don't worry about the output not being exactly what you need. As I said, you can always transform those to whatever you need after you run data trough the ANN, e.g., scaling them.